# Air enters the "electric water pump"

Tags: word-usage

If water doesn't come out through the electric water pump, that is, if it dosen't take up water and it keeps running, air might enter it and it might stop working as well. What will be a natural way to describe that? I read "air entrainment", but I guess that it is rather formal. Is there any informal and natural way to describe that "air entering the pump"?

> Turn it off, or air will enter into it.
>
> Turn it off, or it'll take up air.

Comment: A technical term is "to lose prime" ("prime" referring to the state of being full of water; "priming" meaning to fill the pump with water before turning it on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polite yet instructive way to say it might be:

> Turn off the pump *to prevent* air from entering into it.

This sounds cautionary, but by avoiding "or" it sounds less like a threat!

"Taking *in* air" should be easily understood; not so much "taking *up*", which idiomatically means something else entirely.

Comment: And what about: "taking up air"

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Perhaps "taking *in* air". "Up" is a specific direction.

Comment: So will it sound okay if I say: "The water pump will take in air"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish yes that sounds fine.

Comment: Last question.  What will sound more natural: "take in air" or "enter into"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Definitely "take in air". If you leave the pump on, it is the pump that is drawing air into itself, so the action of "take" shows this. Air "entering" the pump suggests that the air could make its own way in there.

Comment: And what about "draw in air"?  "Turn it off, or it will draw in air".  Or should it be only "take in" (and what would sound more natural between "draw in" or "take in"?)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish There are lots of different ways you could express it. I feel the ones we have already discussed are the most easily understood and idiomatic.